# Overloading methods in an interface using generics as parameters

Tags: java, generics, interface, overloading

I have a Java interface A defining a method which takes another interface B as a parameter.
I want to know if it is possible to overload that method in an implementing class to give as a parameter an object which implements the interface B.
Here's a sample code of what I mean:

```
public interface SampleInterfaceA{
    public void sampleMethod(SampleInterfaceB b);
}

public class ClassB implements SampleInterfaceB{}
public class ClassC implements SampleInterfaceB{}

public class SampleClassA implements SampleInterfaceA{
    @Override
    public void sampleMethod(ClassB b){}
}

public class SampleClassB implements SampleInterfaceA{
    @Override
    public void sampleMethod(ClassC c){}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You dont need to create an override method.
When you call SampleClassA::sampleMethod(B) (B is instant of class B), it will call SampleInterfaceA::sampleMethod(SampleInterfaceB b).

BTW public void sampleMethod(ClassB b){} <- that is overload NOT override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try it, you'll see that `SampleClassA` and `SampleClassB` are seen by the compiler as missing something needed to implement `SampleInterfaceA`.

You need to implement the actual method defined in the interface.

A way to get approximately what you seem to want is to use generics:

```
public interface SampleInterfaceA <T extends SampleInterfaceB>{
    public void sampleMethod(T b);
}

public class SampleClassA implements SampleInterfaceA<ClassB>{
    public void sampleMethod(ClassB b){}
}

public class SampleClassB implements SampleInterfaceA<ClassC>{
    public void sampleMethod(ClassC c){}
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed, and a good example to use templates in java. Thanks!